# Remove battery indicator icon

Tags: release-hera

How can I remove the battery indicator on elementary OS 5.1.2 Hera? I am on a desktop computer, so I don't need that indicator. It is showing up, because I have a Bluetooth mouse, but it is always showing 55% remaining, so it is not useful.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do:

1. `sudo apt-get remove wingpanel-indicator-power`
2. `killall wingpanel`

Comment: How would a normal user figure this out on their own? Like how would I know that the top bar is called wingpanel, and that the only way to customize it is by uninstalling a package. I appreciate your answer but I'd like to learn how to customize my machine on my own. Every other answer was saying to uninstall `indicator-power` and even that is not obvious to figure out.